# How to output data to file but also suppress output on the terminal?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, dev-null

I'm trying to execute a system command in python but I am using > `/dev/null 2>&1` to hide all the output. I'm trying to just display very specific output, but I am also trying to output the data to a file `> grep.txt` so that I can grep the specific data out. However it seems to be going to /dev/null as nothing appears in grep.txt when I use /dev/null in the command.

I have tried the following:

```
#command > grep.txt > /dev/null 2>&1
#command > grep.txt | > /dev/null 2>&1
#command > grep.txt & > /dev/null 2>&1
#command > grep.txt & /dev/null 2>&1
```

but nothing seems to work. It's either one or the other. I just want to save the results to the grep.txt file but also hide the output on the terminal.

I have even tried just using a variable to store the results of the command whilst using > /dev/null but the variable is always empty! So I can only assume that it's going to /dev/null.

Please help! xD

Sorry for the stupid question!

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Do you want the output to go to a file, or do you want it to go to /dev/null?  You can't really do both.

Comment: Why aren't you just going `command 2>&1 > grep.txt ` ?

Comment: Yes, it is either one way or the other. You're telling it to both output and not output at the same time. Consider yourself lucky it even runs at all, with those instructions.

Comment: Note that your title is a bit of an oxymoron - the whole point of /dev/null is that it's nothing, whatever gets sent there is gone.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo. That makes it a legitimate question.

Comment: This has nothing to do with python, so I updated your tags. Feel free to modify as you see fit

Comment: Sorry guys! I have updated the title of this question! Thanks everyone for helping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/dev/null` is equivalent to writing to nothing. It has a file interface, but does not record anything. If you want to retrieve the data, write it to a file:

```
command > grep.txt 2>&1
```

Now `grep.txt` has all the data you were looking for. There will be no output printed to the terminal. You read redirects from left to right: `stdout` goes to file, `stderr` goes to wherever `stdout` is currently going. `2>&1 grep.txt` would read as `stderr` goes to stdout (terminal), `stdout` goes to file, so you will see error output but normal output would go to the file.

Comment: can you show a sample command?

Comment: What did work from your answer was `#command > grep.txt 2>&1`. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @theshape. Sorry, you're right. I screwed up the redirect. You want to move stderr to the updated stdout (file), rather than the original (terminal). Answer updated.

Comment: @theshape. `#command > /dev/null 2>&1 >& grep.txt` sends stdout to null, then sends stderr to the same, then redirects both to the file. You're basically overriding the first part, making the command line needlessly convoluted.

Comment: @theshape. I've updated the answer to explain how the redirects work.